# php pagination code is not working

Tags: php, pagination

Can anyone point me out why my pagination is not working, What I am doing wrong here ? Working on it for a long time. my url generates like : http://localhost/medapp/admin/medorder.php?page=%209.

```
 <?php
   //pagination
    $perpage = 3;
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        }
        else {
          $page=1;
        }
    $start_from = ($page-1)*$perpage;
  //pagination

     $medorder = "SELECT * FROM `medorder` WHERE status='1'  order by ID desc";
     $result = $db->select($medorder);
      if($result){
         $i=0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$i++."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["uid"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["fullname"]."</td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";
       }
// pagination
    $query  = "select * from medorder";
    $result = $db->select($query);
    $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows/$perpage); 
    echo "<span class='pagination'><a href='medorder.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a>";
    for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='medorder.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  }
    echo "<a href='medorder.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></span>";
                         //pagination
    }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query like this by using LIMIT and OFFSET

```
$medorder = "SELECT * FROM `medorder` WHERE status='1'  order by ID desc LIMIT $start_from,$perpage"; //
```

Answer (score 1):

in this following line, you have a space before the $i variable:

```
echo "<a href='medorder.php?page= ".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
```

should be

```
echo "<a href='medorder.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion url is ok now, but pagination is not working..i've 20 rows in DB and it showing all 20 rows in each page.

Comment: @Nazmul  you've calculated `$start_from`, but have never used it.